# Чем можно заменить if

Tags: xsl

только начала разбираться в xsl. Можете подсказать, чем можно заменить if в данном куске кода

```
    <xsl:if test="(parents/father) and (parents/mother) and ((id(parents/father/@id)/parents) or (id(parents/mother/@id)/parents)) and ((brothers) or (sisters))">
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Relative</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Father</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>(Self)</td>
                <xsl:call-template name="family">
                    <xsl:with-param name="x" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Father</td>
                <xsl:call-template name="family">
                    <xsl:with-param name="x" select="id(parents/father/@id)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
```

P.s по заданию if вообще нельзя использовать, а я ничего другого придумать не могу

Comment: Неплохо бы показать исходный xml и задание

Comment: `xsl:choose` ...